# Checking website response within x seconds

Tags: python, python-2.7

Good day the problem I am facing is that I want to check if my website is up or not this is the sample pseudo code

```
Check(website.com)
if checking_time > 10 seconds:
  print "No response Recieve"
else:
  print "Site is up"
```

I already try the code below but not working

```
try:
    response = urllib.urlopen("http://insurance.contactnumbersph.com").getcode()
    time.sleep(5)
    if response == "" or response == "403":
        print "No response"
    else:
        print "ok"
```

Comment: The proper answer is below but to clarify some things: urlopen is a synchronous operation. It will not proceed with execution until it gets a response. It also has internal timeout that you can change by passing `timeout=seconds` argument. Also it will throw an Exception every time request fails for any reason, which means .getcode() only works in case of success. Normally you get error code from the generated exception: `except urllib.URLError as e: print e.getcode()`

Answer (score 1):

If the website is not up and running, you will get **connection refused** error and actually doesn't return any status code. So, you can catch the error in python with simple `try:` and `except:` blocks.

```
import requests
URL = 'http://some-url-where-there-is-no-server'
try:
  resp = requests.get(URL)
except Exception as e:
  # handle here
  print(e) # for example
```

You can also check repeatedly 10 times, each per second to check if there is an exception, if there is you will check again

```
import requests
URL = 'http://some-url'

canCheck = False
counts = 0
gotConnected = False

while counts < 10 :
   try:
     resp = requests.get(URL)
     gotConnected = True
     break
   except Exception as e:
     counts +=1
     time.sleep(1)
```

The result will be available in `gotConnected` flag, which you can use later to handle appropriate actions.

Answer (score 0):

note that the `timeout` that gets passed around by `urllib` applies to the "[wrong thing](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#timeouts-and-cancellation)".  that is each individual network operation (e.g. hostname resolution, socket connection, sending headers, reading a few bytes of the headers, reading a few more bytes of the response) each get this same timeout applied.  hence passing a "timeout" of 10 seconds could allow a large response to continue for hours

if you want to stick to built in Python code then it would be nice to use a thread to do this, but it doesn't seem to be possible to [cancel running threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/1358308) nicely.  an async library like `trio` would allow better [timeout and cancellation handling](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#cancellation-and-timeouts), but we can make do by using the `multiprocessing` module instead:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import perf_counter

def _http_ping(url):
    req = Request(url, method='HEAD')
    print(f'trying {url!r}')
    start = perf_counter()
    res = urlopen(req)
    secs = perf_counter() - start
    print(f'response {url!r} of {res.status} after {secs*1000:.2f}ms')
    res.close()

def http_ping(url, timeout):
    proc = Process(target=_http_ping, args=(url,))
    try:
        proc.start()
        proc.join(timeout)
        success = not proc.is_alive()
    finally:
        proc.terminate()
        proc.join()
        proc.close()
    return success
```

you can use https://httpbin.org/ to test this, e.g:

```
http_ping('https://httpbin.org/delay/2', 1)
```

should print out a "trying" message, but not a "response" message. you can adjust the delay time and timeout to explore how this behaves...

note that this spins up a new process for each request, but as long as you're doing this less than a thousand pings a second it should be OK